# What are the reasons for the game suddenly stopping building production - particularly wonders?

Tags: civilization-4

This seems to happen particularly with Wonders - suddenly the game will inform me that building has stopped on a particular building without any further explanation. The building is then converted into gold.

Why is this happening? How can I tell what has caused it (where do I look) and how can I prevent it happening in future?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When another civilization completes the wonder you are currently building, your progress will be refunded back to you as gold.

As for other buildings, its possible the building under construction has become obsolete.

Comment: @yx - and how, in game, can you know what the cause was?

Comment: @wikis it will tell you, "xzy has been built in a far away country" or if you have met them it will specify the country it was built in.

Comment: I don't know of any possible cause other than the wonder being completed elsewhere.

Comment: Walls are about the only building that go obsolete, if memory serves...

Comment: Many wonders do go obsolete too. So do Monuments.

Comment: Oh yes. And obelisks.